# How many quadrilaterals can be formed using $10$ points in the plane, of which $4$ are collinear?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> $10$ points lie in a plane, of which $4$ points are collinear.  Barring these $4$ points, no $3$ of the $10$ points are collinear. How many distinct quadrilaterals can be drawn?

I have solved it in the following manner:

Considering the first case; $1$ point from the line and rest $3$ out of $6$, which are not collinear I get: $4C1 \cdot 6C3=80$

second case: 2 points from the collinear ones and rest from the 6 I get:
$4C2 \cdot 6C2=90$

third case: using four points from the six non-collinear ones, I get: $6C4=15$

Adding them up I got $185$ ways, but the answer is $209$, which I don't understand how.  Please help.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.  Please explain what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: i am sorry.i have edited my question,thanks for telling.

Comment: If one point is inside the triangle of the other three, there are three possible quadrilaterals from those four points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  To obtain the answer $209$, you would have to consider triangles to be quadrilaterals.

As a check, observe that there are $\binom{10}{4}$ ways to select four of the ten points in the plane to be the vertices of the quadrilateral.  If three or more of the vertices are collinear, we obtain fewer than four sides, so we must subtract these cases from the total.  There is only one way to select all four points on the line.  For each of the four ways we could select three of these four points, there are six ways to pick the additional vertex from the points that are not on the line.  Hence, the number of quadrilaterals that can be formed is
$$\binom{10}{4} - \binom{4}{4} - \binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{1} = 185$$ 
as you found directly.

Comment: I can't see the point, quadrilaterals are supposed to be of. Four.sides.should i consider triangles as quadrilaterals?!

Comment: @123IR  No.  As I said, you are correct.  The only way to obtain the book's answer is to consider triangles to be quadrilaterals.

Comment: well, there seems another possible way, read somewhere that since it is not given the quadrilateral should only be of four points then it can also be of five,i.e, one point may line on one of the edges.considering it, can you solve ?cause I couldn't get. @N.F.Taussig

Comment: The $185$ quadrilaterals we found do include those quadrilaterals that contain five or six points since one or two of the four collinear points may lie between the endpoints of a side of a quadrilateral whose endpoints lie on that line.